# How to store loaded mesh?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I have been trying to store objects which are loaded from an obj files. Basically I am trying create new mesh and store it inside the mesh variable so that later in the Javascript I can refer to that object and change its attribute. However, when I declared this mesh variable and assign the child which is a mesh, after the loading ends, that child disappears and my mesh has nothing in it. Is there a way to create new mesh from a loaded mesh and store them? Thanks!

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh();
//loading the model
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);

loader.load('models/stuff2.obj', function(object){
    //adding object into the scene
    object.name = "trying";
    object.traverse(function(child){
        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
        child.material.map = texture;

    }
    });
    object.position.set(0,0,0);
    scene.add(mesh);
});

console.log(mesh);
```

Comment: Wonder if the answers below worked for you if you could accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a function...

```
var myMeshes = [];
var myMeshHash = {};
function loadMyModel(path, func){
  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(path);
  loader.load(path, function(object){
      object.name = "path";
      object.traverse(function(child){
          if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
          child.material.map = texture;

      }
      });
      object.position.set(0,0,0);
      scene.add(object);
      myMeshes.push(object);
      myMeshHash[path] = object;
      if(func != undefined){
        func(object);
      }
  });
}


//use:
loadMyModel("models/stuff2.obj", function(mesh){
  console.log(mesh);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading a mesh, so you don't need to declare mesh a mesh. You need only use it as a container for the object you load up.

```
var mesh;
//loading the model
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);

loader.load('models/stuff2.obj', function(object){
    //adding object into the scene
    object.name = "trying";
    object.traverse(function(child){
        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
          child.material.map = texture;
        }
    });
    object.position.set(0,0,0);
    scene.add(object);
    mesh = object;
});
// then use it later
$("#my3dworldcontrol").click(function(){
    console.log(mesh);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I tried it but once again the mesh does not contain the same information with the object

Comment: that would be odd, unless all of this is running inside a for loop or other iterator, and then you'd have closure issues. In that case there is not enough code to try it anyhow. If you want answers as unit tested solutions then you should post a fiddle.

Comment: also someone came by and edited out important information from my answer. Literally the code comment "// then use it later" means you cannot use that console log  there because the obj load is async. in that case it would return undefined.

Comment: woops, sorry. Those comments did not actually show up in the one I was editing though, even though the revisions page says I removed the comments. I just added indenting and a semicolon, didn't delete anything.

Comment: @radio Ok thanks! Is there a way to set the command run after the thing has been loaded?

Comment: I edited the answer with a jquery click function you can use to test. watch for the obj load, then click a button. you should see mesh is available as a closure in the click. You do not need to use jquery.

Comment: no worries @2pha I am still getting the hang of things.

Comment: @ExtremelySeriousChicken did you get working? I use threejs quite a bit. This should work. If it did, perhaps you could you accept the answer? Thx!

Comment: @Radio yea! Thanks I was having an error with the async problem. But until that Thanks! However, do you know if there is a javscript way to check if certain events have been completed? I wanted to put that mesh into a global array. However, I cannot do that before the things fully load but I need to... I wish to upvote your answer but I dont have enough reputation points...

Comment: the load manager in the threejs library does  exactly what you want already. There's nothing stopping you from making your own load manager though.  http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/LoadingManager just keep applying your assets to the same loading manager, it will fire when they're all in.

Comment: I realize now you may be talking about other assets such as json. In that case you want to setup functions and what not to fire the above code when the other stuff has loaded up.

Comment: See my new answer for details.